# Is there a way applying regressions to separate data points?

Tags: r

There are a few data points (x and y columns), saying 1000. From the scatter plot, I can tell they can be separated into several groups of points which follow the corresponding linear regression, respectively. How can I use a method or software to automatically separate them?

Comment: Clustering...Have a look at [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/k-means-clustering-in-r/). After applying this, you can filter each clusters (using `group_by()` etc.) and run `lm()`.

Comment: It's call a mixture model. Not a easy method to use and I suggest providing an example. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf

Comment: clustering followed by lm() might work if there is a clear way to separate them